# Mysql - Update first row in table where a column has a null value

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a list of API key. I need to associate an email and a name with these. I want my query to update the name and email on the first row that has null as the email.

```
id    key            name  email

'1', '3046GUGYi7ab', NULL, NULL
'2', 'TXQzL33HVp1W', NULL, NULL
'3', 'YIK6DAnTVU4n', NULL, NULL
```

My attempt is this, But apparently, you cant use the same table in a subquery.

```
UPDATE key_table 
set email="test@x.com", `name`="test"
where id = (Select min(id) from key_table
            where email=null);
```

I'm sure there is a simpel soultion for this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My attempt is this, But apparently, you cant use the same table in a
>   subquery.

```
UPDATE key_table 
set email="test@x.com", `name`="test"
where id = (Select min(id) from key_table
            where email=null);
```

You need to wrap the inner query within a extra subquery if you use the same table name. 
The query below should work.

**Query**

```
UPDATE
  key_table 
SET
    email = "test@x.com"
  , name = "test"
WHERE
  id = ( 
        SELECT
          min_id 
        FROM (
           SELECT
             MIN(id) AS min_id
           FROM
             key_table
           WHERE
             email IS NULL
        )
         AS key_table            
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE key_table
SET email="test@x.com", `name`="test"
WHERE ID=1;
```

This will only affect the first row and change the value

Hope this helps